# QT: How to loop a method every second? C++

Tags: c++, qt, loops, qtimer

I've created a Qt project which displays a circle on a widget. 
Then I have a method which redraws the circle at different positions every time I call the method.
What I want is to run that method in a for loop, say ten times, and be shown each of the 10 positions that the circle is redrawn in every one second.

Something along the lines of:

```
void method::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * p)
{

//code

    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)//do this every second
    {
       method(circle[i]); //co-ordinates change
       circle[i].pain( & painter); //using QPainter
    }

//code

}
```

I've read about QTimer, but do not know how to use it. And the sleep function does not work.

Comment: The sleep function works, but you should never use it in the gui thread. Your users will hate you for it. A second-long sleep in the gui thread literally blocks all event processing for one second. In that time your application doesn't repaint, doesn't react to mouse clicks, keyboard input, requests to close it, etc. It simply hangs.

Comment: Do you mean you want one iteration per second? Or all 10 iterations all at once to happen every second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to trigger an `update()` from the timer event. The `update()` method schedules a `paintEvent` on the widget.

*It is invalid to paint on a widget outside of the `paintEvent`* - that's the mistake that all other answers did at the time I posted this answer. Merely calling the `paintEvent` method is not a workaround. You should call `update()`. Calling `repaint()` would also work, but do so only when you have understood the difference from `update()` and have a very good reason for doing so.

```
class Circle;

class MyWidget : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  QBasicTimer m_timer;
  QList<Circle> m_circles;
  void method(Circle &);
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * p) {
    QPainter painter(this);
    // WARNING: this method can be called at any time
    // If you're basing animations on passage of time,
    // use a QElapsedTimer to find out how much time has
    // passed since the last repaint, and advance the animation
    // based on that.
    ...
    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
       method(m_circles[i]); //co-ordinates change
       m_circles[i].paint(&painter);
    }
    ...
  }
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
    if (ev->timerId() != m_timer.timerId()) {
      QWidget::timerEvent(ev);
      return;
    }
    update();
  }
public:
  MyWidget(QWidget*parent = 0) : QWidget(parent) {
    ...
    m_timer.start(1000, this);
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to remove the loop from the `paintEvent` since the loop behavior is what's supposed to be happening via the timer.

Comment: @tmpearce: That's not how I read the question: as far as I'm concerned, the comment refers to the entire block. The asker is free to elaborate on that.

Answer (score 3):

As you've guessed, [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QTimer.html) is the correct mechanism to use here. How to go about setting it up?

Here's one option:

```
class MyClass : public QObject
{
   public:
   MyClass():i(0)
   {
       QTimer::singleShot(1000,this,SLOT(callback()));//or call callback() directly here
   } //constructor

   protected:
   unsigned int i;
   void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * p)
   {    
     //do your painting here  
   }

   public slots:
   void callback()
   {
      method(circle[i]); //co-ordinates change
      //circle[i].pain( & painter); //don't use QPainter here - call update instead
      update();
      ++i;//increment counter
      if(i<10) QTimer::singleShot(1000,this,SLOT(callback()));
   }

}
```

Comment: Widget painting cannot be done in a timer-triggered slot, outside of `paintEvent`.

Comment: @KubaOber True... I wasn't paying attention to that part of the question, but rather the failure to set up a QTimer correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class MyDrawer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    int counter;
    QTimer* timer;

public:
    MyDrawer() : QObject(), counter(10)
    {
        timer = new QTimer(this);
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(redraw()));
        timer->start(1000);
    }

public slots:
    void redraw()
    {
        method(circle[i]); //co-ordinates change
        circle[i].pain( & painter);

        --counter;
        if (counter == 0) timer->stop();
    }

};
```

Don't forget to run `moc` on this file, although if your class is a QObject you probably already do it.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this.

for(int i=0; i<10;i++)//do this every second
{
   method(circle[i]); //co-ordinates change
   circle[i].pain( & painter);
   sleep(1000);// you can also use delay(1000);

}
```

Use sleep() The function called sleep(int ms) declared in which makes the program wait for the time in milliseconds specified.

Comment: Blocking the event loop will make the GUI unresponsive. Code like this is an instant downvote from me.

Comment: I agree with Kuba that this is not a good idea. Qt is designed around ideas to avoid all this.